# How does Amazon Fire TV know my name/account?

Tags: wireless, mac-address, amazon

I bought a Fire TV stick and inserted it into the HDMI-port of my TV. I was presented with a dialog to select my wireless router so it can connect online.

Just after I did that, it asked me if I am who I am.

So they were able to deduce my account just from my Wifi?

I didn't go to amazon from my "IP of the day" that day before.

How did they match my identity from my wireless network. Did my laptop communicate the ESSID to Amazon before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Amazon Fire TV is pre-configured with your account](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Amazon-CL1130-Fire-TV/dp/B00KQEJBSW):

> Pre-registered to your Amazon account so you can enjoy favourite titles and personalised recommendations

They configure this with your details taken from the account you used to order the device.

Comment: I wonder if they do that when you select gift wrapping at check-out :).  "Merry Christmas, Mom!  ...no, I have no idea where those personalized recommendations came from!"

Comment: @gowenfawr Amazon says that if you check "This will be a gift", then  Amazon will "Deliver the Amazon Fire TV unregistered. The recipient can register the Amazon Fire TV to their own Amazon account when it arrives." It will also ship in an unmarked box with no price on the packing slip.